# How do I properly reference an AtomicBoolean object?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, boolean, java.util.concurrent

I have thread class that is initialized with an AtomicBoolean (set to true).

```
public class WThread implements Runnable {   

private Socket _listenerSocket;
private BufferedReader _br;
private final AtomicBoolean _isRunning;

private final AtomicBoolean _isRunning;    

public WThread(Socket listenerSocket, AtomicBoolean isRunning) {
        _listenerSocket = listenerSocket;
        _isRunning = isRunning;
    }   
}

public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Starting a worker thread.");
        _br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_listenerSocket.getInputStream()));
        _command = _br.readLine();
        dispatchCommand(_command);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    finally {
        try {
            _listenerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}


private void dispatchCommand(String _command) {
        switch(_command) {
            case "fail":
                fail();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
}

private void fail() {
    System.out.println("Failed node.");
    _isRunning.set(false);
    try {
        _listenerSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

Later on, in the same class, I set that boolean to false...

```
_isRunning.set(false);
```

For some reason, it seems like the reference is not working and that the original AtomicBoolean is never set, since some expected actions don't occur in parent threads.

Here's the parent class, which fails to print the "fail":

```
public class ParentThread implements Runnable {
  private ExecutorService _executor = null;
  private final AtomicBoolean _isRunning = null;

   public ParentThread(ExecutorService executor, AtomicBoolean isRunning)(
        _executor = executor;
        _isRunning = isRunning;
   }

   public void run() {
    try {
        while(_isRunning.get()) {
            _executor.submit(new WThread(_isRunning));
        }
        if (!_isRunning.get()) {
            System.out.println("Fail.");
            _executor.shutdownNow();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
   }
}
```

Comment: You didn't show how you're reading it, and is there a reason you're not declaring the field `final`?

Comment: Ive tried final as well at it didn't work. Im reading the variable in a while loop from another thread...so while(_isRunning.get())

Comment: It's hard to tell what's really happening with isolated snippets. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Basically, If I set the isRunning variable to false in the constructor it works fine. If I reference it as _isRunning = isRunning, and set the _isRunning to false, it doesnt work.

Comment: So you're trying to spam child tasks until one of them gets scheduled and pulls the plug on the while loop? What *does* happen?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: The while loop from the parent thread is never broken if _isRunning = isRunning and _isRunning is set to false. But if I pull the plug from the constructor and set isRunning.set(false), the while loop breaks.

Comment: Your 'fail' case doesn't make sense. When the loop exits, `_isRunning` *must* be false. That's not a failure.

Comment: You still haven't posted the "later in the same class". Also, the second class can't be right, because you're assigning a final field twice.

Comment: EJP how insightful

Comment: chrylis I added some of the remaining code, thanks

Comment: Maybe you're getting an `IOException` somewhere, which your code in several places completely ignores.

Comment: I'm definitely not

Comment: Your `while` loop might submit an unlimited number of jobs (a million? a billion? who knows?) before one of these jobs ever manages to set the flag to `false`. At this time, the system load might be too high for the parent thread to run, but anyway, even if it manages to call `shutDown()`, the executor will continue to process the already submitted jobs. But anyway, your code doesn’t even compile due to the duplicate declared field in `WThread`. You have been told to provide a [mcve] already…